# grep() loop for multiple search patterns in R

Tags: r, regex, date

I have information coded in many different values (as levels from a factor), and I would need to unify these levels according to multiple criteria found in each.

Let's say all these factor levels mean actually Spring 2007:
`spring 07, S7, SP07, spring2007, SPRING07`...

Because I have different years and two seasons (Spring and Fall) I would need to replace factor levels according to two criteria: season **and** year. The thing is, I can run this code but it does not modify a thing in the data frame `s2`.

```
for(i in 1: ncol(s2){
  levels(s2[,i]) <- replace(levels(s2[,i]),
                                 (grep("s & 7",levels(s2[,i]),
                                       ignore.case=TRUE)),
                            S2007)
  .....
}
```

What do you think I should modify? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: I guess you should change the values into the data.frame, not only specifying the labels, ie remove the `levels` in your code and keep the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is not correct, it matches the string `"s & 7"` literally since`&` is not a special regex character.

Use `"s.*7"` instead, which means `s` followed by anything 0 or more times, followed by `t`.